# Session value is not being updated in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wondering if did I just found a bug or the amount of hours programming might not let me see the obvious?

Here's an example of my code:

```
class home extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function edit()
    {
        // Prints: John
        print_r($this->session->userdata('name'));

        $this->load->view('home/edit');
    }

    public function ajax_edit()
    {
        $this->session->userdata('name', 'Obama');

        // Prints: Obama
        print_r($this->session->userdata('name'));
    }
}
```

I call the function `ajax_edit` by ajax, and the print is "Obama", which is correct. After that, I refresh the page (to the `edit` function) and the output of the `name` is "John".

Why in god's heaven isn't the session updated with the value "Obama"? It seems that after refreshing it resets or something and backs to the old value "John".

Comment: Where you setting session data?See CodeGodie's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not using the right methods.

In order to set any new information to your CI session, you need to use `set_userdata()`, and in order to retrieve, or to check, whats in the session you use `userdata("key")`.

**Solution:** Rewrite your `ajax_edit()` method code like so:

```
public function ajax_edit() {
    $this->session->set_userdata('name', 'Obama');

    // Prints: Obama
    print_r($this->session->userdata('name'));
}
```

Source: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data